# Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png when using .png

Tags: java, android

I'm new, so maybe I'm doing something completely wrong, but I keep receiving this error when, to my knowledge, I'm using .png files (in the drawable folder I see my two pictures with a .png at the end).

Here's the error I'm getting:

`C:\Users\student\AndroidStudioProjects\MainScreen\app\src\main\res\drawable\water_cup_toggle: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png`

and here's the code in `water_cup_toggle`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/emptywatercupresize2" />
    <item
        android:checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/fullwatercupresize2" />
</selector>
```

I've looked at other similar questions and it seems that they were from people who weren't using .xml or .png files, but nothing for something else that may have gone wrong. Has anyone else encountered this problem or can think of a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow :-)

It looks like you forgot to give an extension to your file.

Rename `water_cup_toggle` to `water_cup_toggle.xml` and you'll be set!